# Create custom css box for a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have looked all over the web for a tutorial or code on how to create a custom css textfield for a plugin. Would really appreciate if someone could help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok bro lets do it

in plugin main file you must register setting for css field

**Like:**

```
register_setting('settings-group', 'css_field');
```

And then in your settings file where you create setting form `(e.g. setting.php)`

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="20" name="css_field" id="css_field" tabindex="1"><?php echo get_option('css_field') ?></textarea>
```

Then call it in your template under the `get_header();`

```
<style type="text/css">
    <?php echo get_option('css_field'); ?>
</style>
```

or you can add in header in plugin main file Like:

```
function wp_css_custome(){
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        <?php echo get_option('css_field'); ?>
    </style>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head','wp_css_custome');
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks deemi! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're trying to put the custom CSS box.

- Inside the customizer
- On it's own settings page
- Inside a widget

More info would let me help answer the question better.